# Why isn't my SVG text centered vertically in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I have a SVG that is well presented in Firefox and Chrome, but in Edge the text doesn't center vertically.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
       <rect fill="#ff0000" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64" rx="8" ry="8" /> 
       <text font-size="32px" alignment-baseline="middle" dominant-baseline="center" fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="85%" x="32" y="32">
           dev
       </text>
    </svg>
```

This is what it looks like when its well presented:

[image]

And this is how Edge is presenting it:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is what you can do: You keep `alignment-baseline="baseline"`. This works correctly on Edge. Then you offset the text on `y` with `dy = font-size/4`

Also I've removed `lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="85%"`from your code since this was offseting the text to the right in Edge.

```css
svg{width:90vh;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
       <rect fill="#ff0000" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64" rx="8" ry="8" /> 
       <text font-size="32px" dy="8" dominant-baseline="baseline" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff"   x="32" y="32">dev</text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Wel, it worked for edge but not for chrome and mozilla

Answer (score 1):

For the most reliable cross-browser behaviour, you should consider not using the `x-baseline` attributes at all. Instead, position the text baseline exactly where you want it.

For example:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
       <rect fill="#ff0000" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64" rx="8" ry="8" /> 
       <text font-size="32px" fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="85%" x="32" y="39">
           dev
       </text>
    </svg>
```